# Call function of a Bean with ajax

Tags: java, email, jsf

Well guys I need to call CorreoController that is a bean, im working with JSF, with ajax
because i need to make a email, and i need to make the inbox.

```
 public Message[] refrescar(String correo, String password, int tipoMail)
{
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "false");
    prop.setProperty(
        "mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    prop.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    prop.setProperty("mail.pop3.port", "995");
    prop.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", "995");
    Session sesion = Session.getInstance(prop);

    switch(tipoMail)
    {
        case 1:try
    {
      // Se obtiene el Store y el Folder, para poder leer el
      // correo.
        Store store = sesion.getStore("pop3");
        store.connect(
            "pop.gmail.com", correo, password);
        Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        // Se obtienen los mensajes.
        Message[] mensajes = folder.getMessages();


        folder.close(false);
        store.close();
        return mensajes;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            break;

        case 2:try
    {
      // Se obtiene el Store y el Folder, para poder leer el
      // correo.
        Store store = sesion.getStore("pop3");
        store.connect(
            "pop3.live.com", correo, password);
        Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        // Se obtienen los mensajes.
        Message[] mensajes = folder.getMessages();

        // Se escribe from y subject de cada mensaje
        /*for (int i = 0; i < mensajes.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(
                "From:" + mensajes[i].getFrom()[0].toString());
            System.out.println("Subject:" + mensajes[i].getSubject());

            // Se visualiza, si se sabe como, el contenido de cada mensaje
            analizaParteDeMensaje(mensajes[i]);
        }*/

        folder.close(false);
        store.close();            
        return mensajes;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            break;
        default:break;

    }

    return null;


}
```

Can anyone help me how to extract those elements mensajes, and how to make in javascript a dinamyc way to make a table to add   with the info collected

Comment: This is covered in a JSF tutorial on the net. You can even find good JSF tutorials in [StackOverflow JSF wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). Besides, you need to specify if you work with JSF 1.2 or JSF 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

To make an AJAX call in JSF, you don't need to use JavaScript. You can try something as following.

. The bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScope
public class CorreoController {
    private List<Message> mensajes;

    public void refrescar(String correo, String password, int tipoMail) {
        // Your logic

        // Update the mensajes list at the end of this method
        this.mensajes = ...;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

. The `xhtml` page:

```
<h:dataTable id="mensajeTable" value="#{correoController.mensajes}" >
    ...
</h:dataTable>

<h:commandButton value="Get mensajes" actionListener="#{correoController.refrescar}" >
    <f:ajax render="mensajeTable" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: In this case, it would be better to have the managed bean as `@RequestScoped`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: not so sure about that :)... `@RequestScoped` is only good if he doesn't do anything to the list (e.g. remove message, mark as read, etc.)... Since he's dealing an inbox, perhaps he should even do lazy loading...

Comment: @Mr.J4mes this approach is not lazy loading... also, you can perform those operations by using GET requests and passing the message ID behind the scenes...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: remove 1 message and have to refresh everything? Nope, it's not an ideal solution for me... We don't even know if his operation is expensive or not... Besides, `lazy` loading is only my suggestion. Assume there are 100000 messages, `lazy` loading is necessary and things like a view for mailbox should not be done with `@RequestScoped`.

Comment: There's a live sample about this in omnifaces showcase page using JSON and `@RequestScoped` managed bean (I've implemented that too in real world app) and it works neat.